# iOS 6 remove address book permission entry

Tags: permissions, popup, ios6, addressbook

So with the new iOS 6 i understand we're suppose to call

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion
```

when we want to access the user's address book.

I wrote some new code in the code block that comes after it and want to test the functionality of that code in regards to how the user responds to the popup asking for permissions.

However I have already called it once and now the permission is stuck on my device, and that popup will never come up since the permission is already there on the phone.

I have gone into Privacy > Contacts and setting it on and off, neither will get the popup to appear. So is there a way for me to right out remove the permission entry in the Privacy section?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Navigate to Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location & Privacy

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, while I couldn't find a way to remove the permission entry from the phone itself but I found a workaround.

I changed the bundleIdentifier to make the phone think of it as a completely new app. This allowed me to get the popup to appear all I want

Answer (score 0):

you may use  `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus` in the `viewDidAppear` methos to check the status of authorization access to address book.

Comment: The problem isn't if the user has permission or not, I just want to recreate the scenario where its the first time the user ran the app. I have tried deleting the app and running it again, but the permission was still there. So is there a way to get the "Allow this app to access your address book" popup to appear again?